# Where does one set the CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture in a Prism application?

Tags: wpf, prism

I'm working on a **WPF** **Prism** application and I need to set the `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` so that new threads have a default culture.

The problem is that I'm not sure where to set this in a Prism application. In the `Bootstrapper`? In `App.xaml.cs`? I'm new to Prism.